# What is the global hotkey to advance the wallpaper slideshow on windows vista/7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-customization, slideshow

I know there is the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> for the desktop. But it is not a global, it only works after a <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no global hotkey. You'll need some special simple app for that, ask a friend-coder :)
Cheers!

Comment: I asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611044/how-to-advance-the-wallpaper-slideshow-on-windows-vista-7-programatically